# GRUB USB not working in windows 7

Tags: grub2, usb, windows-7

I have just re-installed Windows 7 in EFI mode (getting everything working in a new EFI enabled mode) and used boot-repair to get GRUB working again.

However when booting into Windows, there is a very high chance none of the USB ports will work.

This doesn't effect the Ubuntu installation or the GRUB OS selection screen. Only Windows is effected.

Also it only seems to cause a problem if I actually use a USB device. Letting Windows boot by default and using USB during the Windows boot is fine.

Windows 7 did not have a problem before I installed GRUB. If I remove the Ubuntu drive and let Windows 7 boot normally everything is happy again. GRUB is breaking this.

I can provide anything that is needed. But to be honest I don't know where to start in debugging this.

Also my board only seems to provide USB 3 ports that I can tell. So USB 2 may not be an option.

Thanks for any help.